# Change encoding of text file (shell archive or script for antique kernel text to ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, text

I'm writing a small bash script to look up the 1st line of FILEA in FILEB, if it matches then it returns over a text with the filename.

Problem is when i'm extracting text from FILEA and then comparing it with a simple == as an if condition, it returns as different.

I've narrowed down the issue being to the encoding of the 2 files i'm using being different

(FILEA=shell archive or script for antique kernel text)

(FILEB=ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators)

Is there a way to convert FILEA to ASCII to avoid this issue when comparing through UNIX? Or outside of UNIX would work for me too.

Comment: Why not use a tool that ignores line endings in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix uses a single character for line termination.  If you want to convert your file with CRLF to single character termination, you can do the following:

```
sed -e 's/<CTRL-V><CTRL_M>//' filename
```

where `<CTRL-V>` is the Control key pressed with V (do not include `<` and `>` characters in the command.